# Create divs in random places

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I wish to create a div and position it in random places on the screen every 2 seconds. How would I accomplish this using PHP or Javascript? I am ok with using things like CSS.
div:

```js
var blueMass = document.createElement('div');
blueMass.style.position = "absolute";
blueMass.innerHTML = "<img src='./pic/bluemass.png' height='35' width='35' />";
blueMass.id = "bluemass";
blueMass.className = "bluemass";

// my timer
window.setInterval(function(){
    // Create the divs in here
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="bluemass" id="bluemass">
    <img src='./pic/bluemass.png' height='35' width='35' />
</div>
```

Comment: You'd just want to create a timer that gets a random x and y coordinate each iteration. You need to use Javascript to accomplish it, not php.

Comment: I don't see a reason to use PHP, or think that PHP would even be able to do this

Comment: @DanWeber I have a timer, I will edit that in, however I have trouble with making the divs (I'm new to web-development)

Comment: No problem. People are more willing to help with a small issue rather than doing the entire function. Post all of your HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get width and height of document and use that to generate random number. You already have created the element in html, so no need to redo all that in JS.

In your specs you wanted every 2 seconds, so that would be 2000 ms in your timer.

In your timer function you would simply add the left and top of element with the new random numbers.

```js
var blueMassElement = document.getElementById('bluemass');
var currentTop = 0;
var documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

 window.setInterval(function() {
   // Create the divs in here
   
   currentTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentHeight) + 1;
   currentLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentWidth) + 1;
   
   blueMassElement.style.top = currentTop + "px";
   blueMassElement.style.left = currentLeft + "px";
 }, 2000);
```

```css
#bluemass {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bluemass" class="bluemass">
    <img height="35" width="35" src='http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437' />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// no jQuery
$=document.querySelector.bind(document); // create selector
setInterval(function(){
  s=$('div').style;
  s.top=Math.random()*window.innerWidth+'px'; // multiply random (0..1) value by window height (you may want to subtract div height)
  s.left=Math.random()*window.innerHeight+'px'; // ... height ...
},2000)
```

```css
div{position:fixed}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

```js
// with jQuery
setInterval(function () {
  $('#mydiv').css({
    top: Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $('#mydiv').height()) + 'px', // multiply random .width(0..1) value by window height minus div height
    left: Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $('#mydiv').width()) + 'px'
  })
}, 2000)
```

```css
#mydiv{position:fixed}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">div</div>
```

Comment: You may use jQuery instead the first line

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.